# Export test to CSV javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am trying to export a comma delimited string to a CSV that opens when the user clicks on a button. I have found several different examples, but when I have tried to modify them to meet my needs the CSV file does not open. 
This link points to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jecker/d30jx293/19/)

```
<div onClick="exportToCSV('Test.csv');">Test here</div>

function exportToCSV(filename) {
   csv = "test, test1, test2, test3";
   csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
   $(this)
    .attr({
       "download": filename,
       "href": csvData,
       "target": "_blank"
   });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `download` attribute only exists in the `a` tag.

[a](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Try with this:

1. Change the `div` tag to the `a` tag.
2. Pass the reference to the element in the `exportToCSV` function, by using the `this` keyword.

   `exportToCSV(this, 'Test.csv');`
3. Use the reference to the element in the function.

```js
function exportToCSV(me, filename) {
  var csv = "test, test1, test2, test3";
  var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
  $(me) // Reference to the element.
    .attr({
      "download": filename,
      "href": csvData,
      "target": "_blank"
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="exportToCSV(this, 'Test.csv');">Test here</a>
```